# change name of class name when clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class name: .sel-display-on.
When clicked, I want to change it to .sel-display-off with jquery. Is this possible at all? Will the css properties of this new class name be applied?

```
$('.sel-display-on').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // change class name to .sel-display-off
});
```

Comment: Yes, the properties of the new class will be applied. Have you done any research on how to do it? This is very simple and well documented. Look into `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()` and `.toggleClass()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).removeClass('sel-display-on').addClass('sel-display-off');
```

Or, if you are sure that this element won't have any other class names (not very good practice, but may be faster):

```
$(this).attr('class', 'sel-display-off');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).addClass('...');
```

or

```
$(this).attr('class','...');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
$('.sel-display-on').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // change class name to .sel-display-off
    $(this).removeClass('sel-display-on').addClass('sel-display-off');
});
```

You can also do this using toggleClass :

```
$('.sel-display-on').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // change class name to .sel-display-off
    $(this).toggleClass(function(){
       if($(this).is('.sel-display-on'){ 
          return "sel-display-off";
       } else {
          return "sel-display-on";
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all of your questions is "yes"

You can use `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass`, and `attr('class', ...)` as needed.

The `e.stopPropagation` above is not necessary if this is on a `div`, unless you are stopping some other functionality you have bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Yes, use the two functions above to achieve this. Also, the new class will be applied immediately.

One other note: after you remove the class .sel-display-on, then you will no longer be able to select that element using .sel-display-on.